# Deadbolt does not come out all the way sometimes, prevents it from locking. Can it be fixed or should I replace it?

Tags: deadbolt

I've tried checking that the plate is in alignment, it looks fine. But when closing the door and trying the lock, it feels like the deadbolt comes out, but the door opens and the deadbolt is only partially out which keeps it from locking. I've kept the door open and tried the deadbolt several times and it extends completely  most of the time, but not all. So I was wondering if it could be fixed somehow or should I just buy a new one?

Comment: "it extends completely most of the time, but not all." Spray a little graphite or other lock lubricant into the mechanism - to help it work all the time. If that doesn't solve it you might need a slight adjustment of the strike plate. Things shift over time. Probably no need to buy a new one.

Comment: Please provide basic details about your hardware. There's a huge range of possibility here and any answers are broad or wildly speculative.

Comment: Not enough information was provided to answer this question accurately. Please include the make and model of all devices and equipment, photos, diagrams, drawings, and any other information that might help people provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before replacing it, get some graphite lock dry lubricant from your home store and apply it to all the internal surfaces of the lock including the key hole. Disassemble the lock as much as possible to get the lubricant inside the lock. Don't use WD-40 or any liquid type oils as they will get clogged with dirt. If this fails to improve the lock performance, then replacing it is next on the list.

Comment: After applying lubricant if the deadbolt extends fully all the time but still doesn't pass through the strike plate a slight repositioning of the strike plate may solve the problem without purchasing a new deadbolt.